# Accessing inner Fields from different Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

I have a design question in a threading context.
Lets say my model contains 3 Class A,B and C.

I hold a reference to an instance of class A. 
Class A creates multiple class B.
Each of these class B holds a ref of class C and start a background worker to work on class C which process network messages.

This is the idea:

```
Class A
{
   B refB;
}

Class B
{
  public object MyFieldCopy {get;set;}
  public C refC;

  public void ExecuteInOtherThread()
  {
     while(true) 
     {
        // do things with refC, modifying MyField 
     }
   }
}

Class C
{
  public readonly Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> MyField; //init in constructor
}
```

*I actually use properties and not object type,but just trying to improve reading clarity here*

I want to be able to access MyField from class A without blocking the Thread which is working from class B.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Please post your real code, your psudo-code is hard to follow.

Comment: If `C` accessible from `B` you can access `MyField` from `A` via `B`.

Comment: Yes but if I access it while it is modified by the Thread B created ?

Comment: @Scott, I udpdated so it should be better to follow.

Comment: This really feels like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can you explain better what you are trying to do, there may be better solutions to accomplish what you want to do that don't involve copying `Myfield` at all.

Comment: @Scott, i simplified my post.  MyField is in class C, which is processing things in the thread created by Class B. Imagine , class A would be a ViewModel, or an Admin console who want to be able to see whats in MyField without stopping C. Its like your boss coming on your desk while you work, he can look at your screen and see what you doing without interrupting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MyField` will always be a Dictionary you can do that by using `ConcurrentDictionary`.
Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

No matter what you do if two or more threads need to access the same field/memory they can access it one a time so you should place a lock. If you use `ConcurrentDictionary` that will handle it for you.